# How to submit a form with dropdown selected value only?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I want to submit a form which has just one dropdown with language values and i want to submit form and get access to that value so that i can localize some text on the page.

This is the code i am using but not able to access the post values

**html form:**

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<select id="lang">
    <option value="english">Eng</option>
    <option value="arabic">Arabic</option>
</select>
</form>
```

jQuery to submit the form:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var lang = $("#lang").val();
        var Home = 'الرئيسية';

        $("#lang").change(function(){
            cntr = $("#lang option:selected").val();

            if(lang=="arabic"){
                $(".menu ul li a:eq(0)").text(Home);
            }
            $('form').submit();
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Your `<select>` has no `name` attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are missing a "name" attribute on the select:

```
<select name="lang" id="lang">
    <option value="english">Eng</option>
    <option value="arabic">Arabic</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @defau1t The `name` attribute is what the browser uses to serialize the form inputs into a query string or post data. It supplies the key in the  key=value pairs used in POST or GET.

Comment: This is the way forms work, name is the attribute standardized as the identifier for the value in the POST request. Each field in a form needs a key and a value, and we all decided (long, long ago) to use the "name" attribute for the key.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify "name" attribute for you "select" element

Answer (score 1):

`var lang = $("#lang").val();` will only fire when page loads and need `name` for select

Move it inside the change handler so it updates each time

```
   $("#lang").change(function(){
       var lang=$(this).val();
        cntr = $("#lang option:selected").val();

        if(lang=="arabic"){
            $(".menu ul li a:eq(0)").text(Home);
        }
        $('form').submit();
    });
```